# Internal consistency of correlation

Tags: self-study, correlation, reliability

I have this question below , and I am unable to understand what is internal consistency,  can anyone please tell the concept , I have read its wiki page but I couldn't understand how to solve a numerical using that theory , also I couldn't find anything on this platform about this concept .

> Examine , after deducing necessary results , if the following set of correlation coefficients are internally consistent.
> $ r_{12} =0.62 , r_{13}= 0.55 , r_{23} = 0.42 $

Comment: I think you'll need to add the self-study tag since this appears to be a homework problem.  What have you tried so far and what are your thoughts so far so we can guide you figuring this out on your own?

Comment: The term "internal consistency" arises mostly in the domain of reliability and validity of tests/questionnaires. What are yor tests?

Comment: Probably these are bivariate correlations and maybe you should read that first: pg 206-207
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/280839401_Internal_consistency_Do_we_really_know_what_it_is_and_how_to_assess_it

Comment: @statsstudent , I have added a self study tag , actually I am not clear with concept of internally consistent so I  needed to know what does it actually mean to start my work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you assign arbitrarily the three correlations between three variables you may end up with a correlation matrix that is not positive definite. The assignment is consistent if the correlation matrix is positive definite. In your case, it is. Check the eigenvalues.

Comment: Hey , so I calculated the eigen values , and they are 2.06 , 0.58 , 0.34 , hence when the eigen values are positive we say that it is internally consistent or can we simply calculate the determinant of the correlation matrix to say it is positive definite?

Comment: Checking the eigenvalues is a good conceptual description but a poor practical one, because it involves relatively too much calculation.  See the duplicates for answers to all your questions.  In general, *Sylvester's Criterion* is a practical way to address the trivariate case.

Comment: As suggested by whuber, checking one determinant is not enough. You need to check 3 determinants (the leading principal minors). As an alternative, you have the criterion: a symmetric matrix is positive definite if and only if all its eigenvalues are positive.

Comment: @user4422 , you said in this question it is internally consistent but one of the principle minor is negative ( 3rd one)  can you tell me why so ? Actually i have exam in coming week and this question have always been a 10 marker , can you please tell the fixed criteria to check ?